# How many hands is there in poker that are straight with all colors represented

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many hands is there in poker that are straight ( 5 cards in a row - Ace can be
part of the scale A-2-3-4-5 or 10-J-Q-K-A) in which are all four colors represented?

Comment: You might want to replace "colors" with "suits" as a more widely accepted term for poker decks.  Please add your own thoughts about approaching the problem, or give some background motivation for why this is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First select the numbers of the cards, there are $10$ options, the first card can be any card between ace and $10$.

Then you just have to color each card. First choose which of the colors is going to be repeated, there are $4$ options. After doing this there are $\binom{5}{2,1,1,1}=\frac{5!}{2!}=60$ ways to color the cards.

So in total there are $10\times 4\times 60=2400$ possibilites.

Comment: Isnt there 13 options because there is from A(ace) to K(king) possibilities?

Comment: are you allowing things like $Q,K,A,2,3$ ?

Comment: i think not, because this isnt real poker straight?

Comment: then $10$ is the correct number.

Comment: i see now. thank you very much. but can you explain color choosing part? why 5!/2! ?